# Just installed ubuntu 13.04 and cannot login

Tags: 13.04, wubi, login-screen

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04. I used Wubi so I could have a windows dual boot setup because I am new to Linux and wanted to be able to switch back to Windows (7) if need be. 
Everything seemed to install properly.

I entered the initial information: installation size, drive, language, desktop envi, username, and password

I rebooted my computer and selected Ubuntu instead of windows, but when I enter my username and password (the same exact credentials I had typed in for the initial information window a few min. ago) it keeps giving me a wrong password error message. 
I can log in via a guest account, but cant do much from that. I cannot connect to the internet except with Ethernet cord. From the guest account I cannot edit user accounts.

[one thing I did notice that I thought was odd is that on the initial information window I mentioned above I remember it saying Ubuntu 12.04 but when I went into thew guest account and clicked system information it said I had Ubuntu 13.04....]

I am new to Linux, but I'm not a computer idiot and do not know what the problem could be??

Comment: Have you tried reseting your password? Wouldn't hurt

Comment: Wubi is no longer supported as of 13.04. At the Wubi download page, it is said "For 12.04 LTS only.". You'll be better off with a dual boot, but to reset your password, look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

You may want to boot into Single User mode and reset your password from there.

Follow the steps from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).